# Setup local Certificate Authority & integrate with SCEP

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, java, scep

I want setup local Certificate Authority and issue X.509 certificates under my CA. In order to achieve this I am exploring following options such as:

1. OpenSSL/OpenCA
2. BouncyCastle Cryptographic APIs

Further I want to use SCEP to enroll the android device & then use the certificates generated using any of above approaches for the android device communication ?

Can some one please suggest me which options would be best suitable for the local CA setup ?

Comment: OpenSSL provides the routines needed to created a CA which solves the technical need.  Consider that the value of a CA is related to the trust chain based on assumed information control and thus protecting the CA's private key is extremely important.